# Disable url fetching in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, blocking, css

For example, I have a site `www.xxx.com`. It refers to `content.xxx.com/sheets/some.css`, which applies styles that I dislike. Is it possible to block download of this file with Chrome (or some extension)? I just don't want this CSS to be downloaded and applied.

I tried extensions like `Block site`, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a script that replaces the CSS style of a web page by your own CSS.

To achieve that you have to use [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

If you are not in the mood for developing a solution there are Chrome extensions as StyleBot or Stylish where you can apply your own or other users' CSS to determined webpages.

Comment: Problem is with css: it changes frequently, so the only solution is not download the whole file at all, not fixing styles by my owns. I am using `StyleBot` already, but it doesn't help when half of class names changes every weekend. I know name of css, but don't know its content: class names, selectors used etc.